# TNS Ping Oracle Client 11g

Tags: oracle11g, installation, tnsnames, tnsping

I installed an Oracle Client 11g on my Win2012 server. After running the setup, I had set the Environment Variable and then tried to ping the target server.

I get an error saying :

tns 03505 failed to resolve name

I have not added anything in my TNS.Ora, to my surprise the other server from which I am able to successfully ping the target server also doesnot have anything in TNS.ORA file.

Any clue if i have do to few more settings after installing Oracle 11g client  ?

Comment: Oracle might also use DNS for TNS lookup. So if you use the same name for database as for the database server, then it could work.

Comment: If you're seeing different behaviour pinging the same target server, is the sqlnet.ora set up the same on both clients? And if you aren't seeing what ibre5041 suggested, does the other client have TNS_ADMIN set, which would affect where that is looking for tnsnames.ora? i.e., it's *possible* you're looking at the wrong file.